# Page.IsValid always return false even i disabled validation in java script

Tags: javascript, validation, c#-4.0

I have sample taken from

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Enable-Disable-ASPNet-Validator-Client-Side-Validation-using-JavaScript-or-jQuery.aspx

the sample work fine for client side but in code behind he doesn't check  page validation he only set

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('PostBack occured.');", true);

    }
```

when i updated the code behind to validate the page like that

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Page.Validate("Group1");
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('PostBack occured.');", true);
        }
    }
```

the Page.IsValid always return false even i disabled the validation for RequiredFieldValidator with ID="valName" in java script as in the following:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <u>JavaScript</u>
    <hr />
    UserName:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valName" ControlToValidate="txtName" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="*Required" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
    <br />
    Enable Validation:
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox1" onclick="ToggleValidator(this);" checked="checked" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ToggleValidator(chk) {
            var valName = document.getElementById("<%=valName.ClientID%>");
        ValidatorEnable(valName, chk.checked);
    }
    </script>
    <br />
    <br />

</form>
```

Please any help for this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In addition to disabling a validator on the client side...

```html
document.getElementById('<%= valName.ClientID%>').enabled = false;
```

...I added the following to the button click event:

```
valName.IsValid = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Page.IsValid is calculated serverside and doesn't know that you switched the javascript validation off clientside.
Serverside you can check wheter Checkbox1 is checked to ignore validation i.e. add runat="server" to the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox1" onclick="ToggleValidator(this);" checked="checked" runat="server" />
```

and make sure that your serverside clause fires if the page validate OR the checkbox is not checked:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page.Validate("Group1");
   if (Page.IsValid || !CheckBox1.Checked)
   {
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('PostBack occured.');", true);
   }
}
```